# diffrent path for load bootstrap in yii2 on server & localhost

Tags: yii2

diffrent path for load bootstrap in yii2

in local:

```
localhost/akharin2/web/assets/e7c1d11a/css/bootstrap.css
```

in server:

```
example.com/web/assets/6a4bdd46/css/bootstrap.css
```

Loaded from 2 different locations
Why does this problem arise?
How to fix

Comment: Yupik Which folder?

Comment: Yupik  I did not catch.Loaded from 2 different folders.

Comment: Yupik  yes server is running. but why load 2 diffrent path? in local and server

Comment: i think change path in: BootstrapAsset =>  public $css = [
        'css/bootstrap.css',
    ];

Comment: I do not understand exactly your question Yupik

Comment: Your question is related  to different web asset subdirectory ..?  explain your problem  or you  what  you need  to know ..  please

Comment: scaisEdge  yes. in local load from assets/e7c1d11a/css but in server load assets/6a4bdd46/css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `web/assets/xxxxx`  are automatically managed by yii2 framework.

First time an  application component asset as  a .css  or a .js  is required on a host istance   and this is not already available to the framework,  Yii build dinamically a new subselect where store a copy of  the required  asset  element  using a dinamic name. 
This is complety autmatically managed by the frameqork and you don't need to worry for the phisical location of the these asset copies.

you can take a look a this guide if you want know more about assets management  by yii2 http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

Comment: hi. I changed the bootstrap file. but load from another url.
But it seems to me that when it was loaded, another bootstrap was built and the bootstrap was not changed.

Comment: where you have changed  the bootstrap file  ..?  inside asset ?  be careful that when you update  with composer  you can override your modified  file .. You should change in bower dist and make a copy for avoid override .. then delete the assest related  to bootstrap .. the modified  is  inserted  in a new asset   ..